# Lemma $10.6$ - Lectures on Mean Curvature Flow by Xi-Ping Zhu

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I'm studying by myself Mean Curvature Flow and I'm stuck in the proof of the lemma $10.6$. I will put some notations before the lemma:

[image]

[image]

My doubts are how the terms highlighteds are derived. I couldn't do anything that helps me to derive $(1)$. My attempts for $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ are the following:

$(2)$:

$\begin{align*}
 H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \frac{\partial^2 \nu^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} \nu^{\beta} &\overset{(10.5)}{=} H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial X^{\alpha}}{\partial x^m} - \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha} \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \right) \nu^{\beta}\\
&= H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( h_{jl} g^{lm} \right) \frac{\partial X^{\alpha}}{\partial x^m} + h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial^2 X^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i \partial x^m} - 
 \frac{\partial \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i}  \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} - \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \right) \right] \nu^{\beta}\\
&= H \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( h_{jl} g^{lm} \right) \frac{\partial X}{\partial x^m}, \nu^{\beta} \right)_{N^{n+1}} + H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial^2 X^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i \partial x^m} \nu^{\beta} - H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta}
 \frac{\partial \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i}  \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \nu^{\beta} - H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \right) \nu^{\beta}\\
&= H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} h_{jl} g^{lm} \frac{\partial^2 X^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i \partial x^m} \nu^{\beta} - H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta}
 \frac{\partial \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i}  \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \nu^{\beta} - H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \right) \nu^{\beta},
\end{align*}$

but I couldn't see why $- H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \right) \nu^{\beta} = 0$.

$(3)$:
It is only replace what I marked as $(2)$ in $(10.7)$ and do a reindexing appropriately.

$(4)$:

$\begin{align*}
H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \left( \frac{\partial \overline{\Gamma}_{i\delta}^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{y}^{\gamma}} \nu^{\gamma} \frac{\partial X^{\delta}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\beta} - \frac{\overline{\Gamma}_{\rho\sigma}^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial x^j} \nu^{\sigma} \nu^{\beta} \right) &= H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \left( \frac{\partial \overline{\Gamma}_{ij}^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{y}^{\gamma}} \nu^{\gamma} - \frac{\overline{\Gamma}_{j\sigma}^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i} \nu^{\sigma} \right) \nu^{\beta}\\
&= H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \left( \frac{\partial \overline{\Gamma}_{ij}^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{y}^{\delta}} - \frac{\overline{\Gamma}_{j\delta}^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{y}^i} \right) \nu^{\delta} \nu^{\beta}\\
&= H \overline{g}_{\alpha\beta} \left( \frac{\partial \overline{\Gamma}_{ij}^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{y}^{\delta}} - \frac{\overline{\Gamma}_{\delta j}^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{y}^i} \right) \nu^{\delta} \nu^{\beta}\\
&= H \left( \overline{\nabla}_{\nu} \overline{\nabla}_{e_i} e_j - \overline{\nabla}_{e_i} \overline{\nabla}_{\nu} e_j, \nu \right)_{N^{n+1}}\\
&= H \overline{R}_{0i0j},
\end{align*}$

where I used the definition of tensor curvature given on page $6$ of [this](http://www.felixschulze.eu/images/autumn_2017/notes_mcf_16112017.pdf) lecture notes written by a former Huisken's student.

P.S.: there is a proof of this lemma in the paper [Contracting convex hypersurfaces
in Riemannian manifolds by their mean curvature](https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_152768/component/file_152767/content) by Gerhard Huisken on page $469$, it's the theorem $3.4$.

Thanks in advance!